# arctic p311 bluetooth headset crappy sound

Tags: bluetooth, headset

i connected my new arctic p311 bluetooth headset to my laptop. I can hear and speak as expected.

But the sound quality of what i can hear is really bad. 
When i change audio hardware setup in phonon to high fidelity the sound is great but i can not use the microphone.

Does that mean whenever i wan to use the microphone i must live with the bad sound quality of the headphones?

Or can i use the mic and the headphones with high sound quality?
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is still [not possible](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.audio.pulseaudio.general/10998) currently in Ubuntu or Linux in general, though [it should be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A2DP#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29).